# Laravel Blade Undefined Variable Error But The Variable Is Defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

This is a really odd error. In my blade view:

```
    <?php //dd($site); ?>
    @if($site==='site1')
```

On the second line `@if($site==='site1')` I get a `Undefined variable: site` error. But if I uncomment out the dump and die I get the `$site` variable set. It's literally on the very next line that it tells me it doesn't have a set `$site` variable in blade. Is my syntax wrong on the `if` statement?

It looks correct to me, the documentation gives:

```
@if (count($records) === 1)
    I have one record!
@elseif (count($records) > 1)
    I have multiple records!
@else
    I don't have any records!
@endif
```

Adding a space between `@if` and the first paren `(` made no difference.

I tried clearing the view cache but that made no difference too. Every other change gets registered, for example if I remove the `$` that prepends the variable name I get an undefined constant error. I'm developing locally.

I'm at a complete loss because even though the variable is three levels deep in blade I am passing it correctly and I confirmed it with the dump and die. The conditional just won't pick it up.

I pass it into the view like this:

```
 @component('pages.common.component.mycomponent',['site'=>$site])  
 @endcomponent
```

And one more level up like this:

```
 @component('pages.common.parent.mycomponent',['site'=>'site1'])  
 @endcomponent
```

Any ideas I would be very grateful for!

**EDIT:**

The `dd()` call outputs:

> "site1"

As a string.

Comment: hi @JeanneDark thanks, but not sure what you mean. If I remove the `?>` and move it below the second line, it won't be valid, as the second line is blade syntax not php syntax. If I move the entire first line below the second line I just get the error before it hits the dump and die. Maybe I am misunderstanding you though.

Comment: Can we see the result `dd($site);` ?

Comment: This is a bug and fixed on 7.1.3 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/31919

Comment: @xNoJustice updated.

Comment: @sta that looks different, involving classes. here i am just passing a variable through multiple blade components.

Comment: You passing through component? Pass directly, hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

The answer was later in the 2nd level (parent to the component in which I had the error) there were TWO declarations to this third component, one of which was not passing the `$site` variable. Of course, because I was using an inline `dd()` method of debugging in the third component it didn't make sense at first, as it hit the first declaration but not the second.

What helped me was calling the render method on the entire view and outputting it as a string, so I could see it was there in the first declaration but not in the second.

So in the controller, instead of:

`return view('pages.routes.parent', $params);`

I did:

`dd(view('pages.routes.parent', $params)->render());` to get the entire view as one string output to trace where I was missing the data. Inspecting the `storage` compiled views didn't help as they are partials particular to each component or view.

Note for this to work I had to wrap the `@if` conditionals in another `@if` conditional, checking if the `$site` variable was `isset()`.

Hope this can help someone else in the future.